# Is It Possible to use getElementsInfo on elements already retrieved through getElementsInfo?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am wondering if there is a way to call casperjs getElementsInfo twice, I've tried to do something similar to below with no luck. Wondering if there is work around for this?

```
var rows = this.getElementsInfo('table.dateentrytable tr');
var cells = rows[0].getElementsInfo('td');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, a solution i've found for cases like this use XPath and a while loop, for example, this code loops through a table with undefined number of rows:

```
i= 1;
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
 while (this.exists(x('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[1]'))) {
     this.echo(this.fetchText(x('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[1]')));
     this.echo(this.fetchText(x('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[2]')));
     i++;
}
```

In your case instead echo() use getElementInfo().

Answer (score 0):

#### No, you cannot call [`getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) twice on a previously retrieved element.

CasperJS returns an array of JSON objects representing the elements you selected in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "align": "left",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "id": "hplogo",
            "onload": "window.lol&&lol()",
            "style": "height:110px;width:276px;background:url(/images/srpr/logo1w.png) no-repeat",
            "title": "Google"
        },
        "height": 110,
        "html": "<div nowrap=\"nowrap\" style=\"color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;left:214px;top:70px\">France</div>",
        "nodeName": "div",
        "tag": "<div dir=\"ltr\" title=\"Google\" align=\"left\" id=\"hplogo\" onload=\"window.lol&amp;&amp;lol()\" style=\"height:110px;width:276px;background:url(/images/srpr/logo1w.png) no-repeat\"><div nowrap=\"nowrap\" style=\"color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;left:214px;top:70px\">France</div></div>",
        "text": "France\n",
        "visible": true,
        "width": 276,
        "x": 62,
        "y": 76
    }
]
```

As you can see, the innerHTML is represented as a string that is accessible by calling the `html` attribute (i.e. `rows[0].html`).

If possible, you should just modify your selector that you pass to `getElementsInfo()`:

```
var cells = this.getElementsInfo('table.dateentrytable tr td');
```

Otherwise, if this is not an option, you can parse the resulting HTML string (i.e. `rows[0].html`) into a DOM element and select the cells using `getElementsByTagName()` or an equivalent method.